# How to add a rowid to a resultset of an oracle stored procedure in java

Tags: java, .net, oracle, jdbc, oracleclient

If I'm developing application in .Net with Oracle, there is `OracleCommand` class which has a property `AddRowId=true`. This statement includes a RowId column in the resultset.

But I can't find anything similar in JDBC's `OracleStatement`. Can someone help me on this? I really need to get rowid being returned in the resultset of my stored procedures without modifying the stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "ROWID" pseudocolumn to your queries to get the Row ID.

ex:

```
SELECT name, ROWID
FROM People
```

Comment: as i said, i can't edit the queries. Besides, these are not normal select statements. We are talking about stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't edit the stored procedure, you have no way of providing a Java or .Net program with the ROWIDs of the rows being returned by the stored procedure. The ROWID is *only* available directly via the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: @Faisal pls show that code using addrowid.  Per the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleCommandClass.htm#i997582), "This ROWID column is hidden and is not accessible by the application. To gain access to the ROWIDs of a table, the ROWID must explicitly be added to the select list without the use of this property."

Comment: @Faisal I think you'll find AddRowId isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: @GriffeyDog http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleCommandClass.htm says it adds the ROWID as part of the select list

Comment: @Faisal have you tried it? Pls show the code you say works (by just using "AddRowid=true" flag).

Comment: @Faisal Read the documentation more carefully. Like tbone said, it has this: "This ROWID column is hidden and is not accessible by the application. To gain access to the ROWIDs of a table, the ROWID **must explicitly be added to the select list** without the use of this property."